# Why pass a offset param to Java BufferedOutputStream.write?

Tags: java, file-io

I am not quite understanding why you would ever want to pass  a offset param to Java BufferedOutputStream.write  via the method `public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len)`  ?   What is a use-case where you might want to start from a non-Zero offset of the b parameter?    Even though you can do it, I don't see why you would want to.  From what I can tell, using it is un-necessary 99% of the time?

Comment: When the data in the byte array that needs to be written is *not* at the beginning of the array.

Comment: When you've used the [`BufferedInputStream.read(byte[], int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)) method, with a non-zero second parameter to put the data into the array.

Comment: If you're asking because you're a C/C++ programmer, a corresponding method would take a `char*` and the `len`, but no offset, because offsetting is easily done with `ptr + offset`. That cannot be done in Java, so to prevent need for *copying* the bytes to another buffer, most methods in the JDK that accepts a `byte[]` will have an overload accepting `byte[], offset, len`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say I have a 20M byte array containing an image and I want to send the data for that image over the network.  (Say I'm writing an HTTP server.)  A network buffer is only so large - I'm probably going to want to write that image data to the TCP pipe in more manageable chucks.  (4k?)

By having that offset it prevents me from having to do a bunch of array copies.  So I can use it like this:

```
byte[] image = loadImage();
int chunkSize = 4096; // 4k
int chunks = image.length / chunkSize;
for (int i=0; i<chucks; ++i) {
  os.write(image, i*chunkSize, chunkSize);
}
```

Note you're passing in the same byte array each call to write.  It's just reading a different part of it.

DISCLAIMER: This example is overly simplified, ignoring dealing w/ the end of the image where it doesn't line up w/ the chucks, but that's immaterial to the point.

Comment: The other case you would want to do this is if you are able to flush out some of the processed data.  So, for example, if you are zipping up a 10gb file, you probably only need and want to have 1M of it in memory at a time.  You could bring in some of it, start DEFLATE, and start sending out the results while you are still processing.  Removing the need to store the full 10g in memory.

Comment: You would definitely not want to do this. You should just write the entire array in one call. TCP will do all the management necessary.

Comment: @keredson Ok, I think I get the gist of what your saying although your use-case would already be handled by TCP layer wouldn't it?  For example, this guy used a non-0 offset:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169739/java-tcp-socket-data-transfer-is-slow     I hope you understand where my question still lies?

Comment: @djangofan That is exactly my point. The example is artificial and poor practice. The fact that network buffers even exist is irrelevant to the operation of `OutputStream.write()`: it is defined to block until everything has been written. Writing your own loop to accomplish what it already does is completely pointless, and can be counterproductive.

Comment: @EJP I hear you but still wondering about an answer to my question, in general.  Studying for my OCP exam.

Comment: @djangofan The other answer is sufficient, but I will add that the `offset` parameter is zero in 99% of the Java I/O code I have ever written, if not 99.99%, over a period of twenty years. It's there because it has to be there for completeness, but in practice it is rarely used.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, I thought as much.  That pretty much answers my question.

Comment: Obviously it's a contrived example.  The question was why you would ever do it, and this is a fairly common pattern in Java and other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually used this API, which was for a high speed I/O that reused a single `byte[]` buffer to read in data then wrote it out, but certain parts of the payload were skipped.

Comment: Thanks for the simple, to the point answer.   Still looking for perhaps a more solid answer also.